# Value split is not a member of (String, String)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-submit

I am trying to read data from Kafka and Storing into Cassandra tables through Spark RDD's.

Getting error while compiling the code:

```
/root/cassandra-count/src/main/scala/KafkaSparkCassandra.scala:69: value split is not a member of (String, String)

[error]     val lines = messages.flatMap(line => line.split(',')).map(s => (s(0).toString, s(1).toDouble,s(2).toDouble,s(3).toDouble))
[error]                                               ^
[error] one error found

[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Below code : when i run the code manually through interactive `spark-shell` it works fine, but while compiling code for `spark-submit` error comes.

```
// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = Set[String] (kafka_topic)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> kafka_broker)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]( ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

// Create the processing logic
// Get the lines, split
val lines = messages.map(line => line.split(',')).map(s => (s(0).toString, s(1).toDouble,s(2).toDouble,s(3).toDouble))
lines.saveToCassandra("stream_poc", "US_city", SomeColumns("city_name", "jan_temp", "lat", "long"))
```

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: please don't format proper nouns as code. Kafka and Cassandra merely need an initial capital, and that's it - they are not themselves code. However, things like `spark-shell` are OK, since the code formatting is appropriate for console I/O (presuming `spark-shell` is a command that is typed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` returns a *tuple* of key and value (since messages in Kafka are optionally keyed). In your case it's of type `(String, String)`. If you want to split the *value*, you have to first take it out:

```
val lines = 
  messages
   .map(line => line._2.split(','))
   .map(s => (s(0).toString, s(1).toDouble,s(2).toDouble,s(3).toDouble))
```

Or using partial function syntax:

```
val lines = 
  messages
   .map { case (_, value) => value.split(',') }
   .map(s => (s(0).toString, s(1).toDouble,s(2).toDouble,s(3).toDouble))
```

Answer (score 3):

All messages in kafka are keyed. The original Kafka stream, in this case `messages`, is a stream of tuples `(key,value)`.

And as the compile error points out, there's no `split` method on tuples.

What we want to do here is:

```
messages.map{ case (key, value)  => value.split(','))} ...
```